# PhpStorm 9 disable expand on tab

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

In JavaScript files, if I write for example `record` and then I press tab, then the editor automatically expand it to `<record></record>`.

How can I disable this?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you please show a screenshot of such file. In general .. you should not have such completion in JavaScript files (unless, of course, it's another language injected, like XML/HTML).

Comment: Yes, I added it. please look.

Comment: AFAIK it should not be happening like that in JS context .. unless, maybe, it's a ReactJS/JSX ... What menu do you see if you `Alt+Enter` somewhere there? In any case -- try disabling Emmet for JSX at `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Emmet | JSX` -- any better?

Comment: this solved it: disabling Emmet for JSX at Settings/Preferences | Editor | Emmet | JSX

Comment: would you please add it in an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking such completion (as shown on your second screenshot) should not be working in JavaScript file, unless it's a:

- language injection fragment (HTML/XML and alike) .. which is not the case here because it's not inside string literal;
- some ReactJS/JSX kind of code

Considering the last one: try disabling Emmet for JSX at `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Emmet | JSX`.

Answer (score 0):

Open Settings->Editor->General->Smart Keys and uncheck "Automatically insert closing tag".

If you're still experiencing this problem, it might because of the following issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-119253 (it should be fixed in 138.2128, 138.2206 but there are several similar open bugs).

Comment: I still have the same result. I added a screenshot of my Smart Keys settings, please look